# Using thread to read a file and passing data

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, io

I was researching about Python and threading, more specifically, returning data from a method being called in a thread. All  my research lead to Queues. However, I'm unsure if I actually implemented it correctly, and I have a question.

```
import threading
import queue


def construct_list(read_file, backup):
    with open(read_file) as read_obj:
        backup.put(read_obj.readlines())
    backup.task_done()


backup_list = queue.Queue()
read_thread = threading.Thread(target=construct_list, args=("list.txt", backup_list,))


read_thread.start()
read_thread.join()

while backup_list.empty() is False:
    print(backup_list.get())
```

Questions:

1. Have I correctly implemented and used Queue? I've seen examples where the code calls `queue.join()` is that needed here?
2. When printing the Queue using the while loop, it prints it like so:

   ['KeePass']
   How can I print it without the [''] and just get the plain string KeePass?

Comment: 1. Not sure about python thread libraries
2. Aren't you just printing a list? Try backup_list.get()[0] instead.

Without going too much into your code, should backup list ever contain more than 1 element? Are you trying to print out all items in it? Why not just do `for item in backup_list: print(item)`

Comment: @bhow - but if there are other items in the list, I would have to get the length of the queue, run a for loop based on the length and plug that into the `[]`

Comment: @bhow - Because Queue can't use a for loop to iterate, I tried this, it throws an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main issue with threading is making sure nothing will explode, or if something will explode you have that scenario covered and you are willingly letting it explode. With that in mind and the fact that there is no feasible way for automating that part of threading with current architecture of operating systems without sacrificing benefits of multithreading let us get into your choices and correctness of your implementation.

```
def construct_list(read_file, backup):
    with open(read_file) as read_obj:
        backup.put(read_obj.readlines())
    backup.task_done()
```

Okay, you seem to have  this thing backwards. If you read something and based on that you post data/command/anything to queue for process you don't call `task_done()` since you only requested a task to be done. When you post such requests you don't perform that task.

Second issue here is writing those commands to queue with no timeout. By default `queue.put()` is blocking and has no timeout, this is not a mistake, I'm just pointing this out to make sure this is conscious decision and it has to be taken into account when extending functionality of this example.

```
read_thread.start()
read_thread.join()
```

Well... This actually defeats whole idea of multithreading. Idea being able to perform multiple tasks in parallel, with call to `join()` here you are blocking main thread until worker thread finishes. Which basically means you are creating a thread and performing all operations twice as slow as with a single thread. Whole idea of using queue is for multiple threads to communicate with each other WHILE THEY BOTH ARE RUNNING. You shouldn't join other thread in such way, just do it after  you no longer need it and queue has been processed.

```
while backup_list.empty() is False:
    print(backup_list.get())
```

First you shouldn't assume that if `empty()` returns `False` your `get()` call will not block. If main thread was GUI thread or any other variant that needs continuous running you would want to call it with non-blocking calls and deal with non-processing items by skipping.

Second, since this queue is uses for communication this is the place that you'd want to signal that task is done. Your task is calling `print()` function on elements that get passed to queue. After calling print on that element you can signal that task has been completed with `task_done()` call.

Lastly, no in this scenario calling `join()` on queue is not needed.

@edit: as for second question `When printing the Queue using the while loop, it prints it like so: ['KeePass'] How can I print it without the [''] and just get the plain string KeePass?` - this is not related to neither threads nor queues. This is an issue that you read contents of file with `readlines()` and dump result into backup list. I believe you are working on example of continuous reading file, then either split those results into single lines or more appropriately use `read()` instead.

Comment: How did you learn multi threading? what resources did you use?